# Importar tabelas do MySQL para o Azure

Tags: tabela-banco-de-dados, microsoft-azure

Alguém tem alguma dica como importar tabelas do MySQL para o Windows Azure, estou encontrando essa dificuldade, sei que o Azure trabalha com a extensão bacpac e o workbench trabalha com o sql.

Li a documentação da Microsoft, mas mesmo assim, não consegui.

Comment: Vc não consegue importar, ou não consegue conectar no seu MySQL hospedado no Azure? Qual serviço está usando - Azure MySQL Database ou ClearDB MySQL no Azure ou é uma VM com MySQL instalado?

Comment: Bom dia Thiago, parece que eu consegui criar um database MySQL no Azure, que não sei se preciso configurar o firewall, não sei como conectar no MySQL. Primeira vez que subo um sistema web, estou dando uma olhada na documentação, mas não estou obtendo muito sucesso.

Comment: Vamos lá existem 3 serviços de MySQL no Azure para usar "out of the box". Me confirma: É um [Azure Database for MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mysql/)?

Comment: Sim, criei um Banco de Dados do Azure para MySQL (Virtualização)

Comment: Legal, agora já sei o ambiente. Me diz exatamente o que vc está fazendo, e qual erro está obtendo.

Comment: Consegui configurar o MySQL Workbench para conectar ao MySQL do Azure. Através do Workbench criei a base de dados e as tabelas. Quero saber se esse procedimento de criar através do Workbench ele cria na Azure tbm ? Sabe me informar se qdo eu crio a base com as tabelas, qto tempo leva para estar ativo no ar ? Como posso reiniciar o tomcat do Azure ?

Comment: Espera aí, vc está misturando as bolas. Tomcat nada tem a ver com MySQL. É pelo que entendi, vc nem tentou fazer o procedimento do Azure Database MySQL. Vou pedir para fechar sua pergunta, e quando vc realmente tiver tento dificuldade em algo que está tentando e não está conseguindo, abra uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Desculpa, me expressei mal, do banco de dados eu havia feito o procedimento acima para criar... Consegui conectar no MySQL do azure através do Workbench. Pelo Workbench eu criei as tabelas, esse procedimento está correto ? Tem como eu verificar dentro do Azure as tabelas que eu criei ?